# entity framework use linq to return join tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

i have some tables:

```
table1:
id1
fk_tb2 // this is the fk to table2

table2:
id2
fk_tb3 //this is the fk to table3

table3:
id3
name3
```

Now i want to return a table like:
id1
fk_tb2
name3

anyone knows how to do that? Thanks

Regards,

Comment: Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750146/linq-select-to-new-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join tables and use anonymous type to return required fields:

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.fk_tb2 equals t2.id2
join t3 in table3 on t2.fk_tb3 equals t3.id3
select new { t1.id1, t2.id2, t3.name3 }
```

Comment: thanks, and what would be the return type? because i need to write it in a function that returns this.

Comment: Anonymous type will be anonymous :) You can't return anonymous objects from methods. If you want to return these three values, then create some class `public class Foo { public int Id1 { get; set; } ...` which will have three properties Id1, Id2, Name. And return instance of this class instead: `select new Foo { Id1 = t1.id1, Id2 = t2.id2, Name = t3.name3 }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your navigations well mapped, you can do something like

```
var m = from tb1 in dbContext.table1
        select new {
                     id1 = tb1.id1,
                     fk_tb2 = tb1.table2.tb2,
                     name3 = tb1.table2.table3.name3
                   };
```

else you can do

```
var m = from tb1 in dbContext.table1
        join tb2 in dbContext.table2 on tb2.id2 equals tb1.fk_tb2
        join tb3 in dbContext.table3 on tb3.id3 equals tb2.fk_tb3
        select new {
                     id1 = tb1.id1,
                     fk_tb2 = tb2.id2,
                     name3 = tb3.name3
                   };
```