# How to get the data results to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I should probably preface by saying I am relatively new at mvc coding

I have a data table that contains a name, address, lat and long values. I need to get the lat and long values into my controller in mvc 5 (there are about 10 records) and use those records.

I know probably the best way is `IEnumerable` but what I cannot figure out is how to get the values from the database to the `IEnumerable` (or list whichever is better)

Is this the best way to do this and if so could someone point me in the right direction with either some sample code or a good tutorial

So far what I have come up with is like this:

```
using (var context = new dbContext())
{
    foreach (var loc in context.Locations)
    {
        var locLat = loc.Lat;
        var locLng= loc.Long;
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.Locations` _is_ a collection.  You can use that.

Comment: so how would I add that to an enumerable or list?  That is where I am stuck.  I appreciate the help

Comment: It _is_ an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You don't need to do anything.  But learn about LINQ.

Comment: what do you actually want to do with your `Locations`?

Comment: I am trying to compare them with other Locations to the distance between them.  I have that written in another method so I would pass them to that method

Comment: I don't understand the downvote but thanks anyhow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a foreach loop, just use something like this:

```
var coordinates = context.Locations
                         .Select(loc => new { Lat = loc.Lat, Lng = loc.Long })
                         .ToList();
```

`coordinates` will then be a list of coordinate objects (Lat, Lng) which you can iterate through or do whatever you want with.

Comment: I think this is what I need how would I go about getting the values from the list?

Comment: Once you have a list, you can treat it like any old list. `coordinates.First().Lat`

Comment: Ok thank you very much Joe -- Then you would just iterate through the list with a for statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```cs
using (var context = new dbContext())
 {
       var newList = (from record in context.Locations
                  select new { lat = record.lat, log = record.log}).ToList();

 }
```

[Linq select to new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750146/linq-select-to-new-object)