# How to get the result of an API call in a single class?

Tags: c#, api

I have two classes which are the result of a call to an API:

```
{
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string name {get;set;}
 public address address {get;set;}
}

public class address
{
 public class address1 {get;set;}
 public class address2 {get;set;}
 public class city {get;set;}
}
```

I also have this code which stores API call in customers:

```
var customers = GetCustomers(bearerToken);
```

and the DB insert:

```
connection.Execute("dbo.Insert_Customer @ID, @Name", customers);
```

The issue I am having (I'm new to C sharp and API), I'm trying to get the contents of customers on one level.

However, address has two - contents are `Address.Address1`, `Address.Address2`.

I can't write the classes in that way due to the API.

Is there a way I can re-write this.

I know I need another list but not sure where to begin.

Ultimately this data is to be stored in a DB hence needs to be all on one level.

Hope all the above makes sense.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, give info about what the GetCustomers method returns. Moreover, I suggest you use Entity Framework due to security problem because you can face SQL Injection Attack

Comment: Looks like you have typos in the address class.  address1, address2, and city are all strings right?  What do you mean "I'm trying to get the contents of customers on one level."?

Comment: The GetCustomers connects to API and pulls in the response the two classes shown above, therefore they could be a return such as, Id=12, name=“joe smith”, address= “address contents” (address1=“101 street”, address2=“Flat”, city=“london”).  In the customer object it is stored as such, however when I save to db for address it stores address contents. I need it to save address1, city separately like the other fields. Hence saying it’s two levels. Just trying to see via list<> if there was a way I could re-do this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saying that you want to have a single type with Id, Name, Address1, Address2 and city at the same level so that you can pass it all to the stored procedure in the database, then you could use Linq to create a dynamic object with the data for each of the two classes like this -> [Linq select to new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750146/linq-select-to-new-object/36206879)

Comment: Thanks I used Linq in the end, you helped me in gaining knowledge around this area.  Very much appreciated