# How to generate treeview using Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following three tables,

Region Table,

| RegionId | RegionName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | North Region |
| 3 | South Region |

Branch Table

| BranchId | BranchName | FkRegionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roswell Rd | 3 |
| 2 | Test | 2 |
| 3 | Piedmont Ave | 2 |
| 4 | Ashford Dunwoody | 1 |

User Table

| UserId | FirstName | FkBranchId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hasa | 9 |
| 2 | Jane | 1 |
| 3 | Joyce | 7 |
| 4 | Jane | 1 |
| 5 | John | 3 |
| 6 | Sharon | 8 |

As mentioned above, each branch has its region and each user has a branch. I need to create following JSON for my frond-end usage. Therefore I need to populate data in order to create this JSON.

```
Region1
    Branch1
        Jane
        Paul
        Alex
    Branch2
        Neil
        Kaja
        Alex
Region2
    Branch4
        Ama
        Hema
        Ira
    Branch5
        Laura
        Tim
        Yea
```

How can I do this using C# and linq?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your implementation not working as expected?

Comment: @DekuDesu Sir, I'm bit new to linq, It's hard for me to imagine how to do something like this

Comment: I would assume your data is on a database. Is it using linq a requirement you can not avoid? Because if you are not familiar with linq but you know how to retrieve the data using regular SQL, I would suggest you going the SQL way.

Comment: @Cleptus But problem is, this project not using SQL and using EF. :( its a project requirement by our University

Comment: get the main root object with related data and serialize. NewtonSoft...

Comment: @PowerMouse Can u please provide me code

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm
as @Muhammad Kamran answered, use that result to serialize to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsonResponse = "[{\"UserId\":195,\"FirstName\":\"Carlton\",\"BranchId\":4,\"BranchName\":\"Test\",\"RegionId\":1,\"RegionName\":\"Admin\"},{\"UserId\":223,\"FirstName\":\"Lorenza\",\"BranchId\":4,\"BranchName\":\"Test\",\"RegionId\":1,\"RegionName\":\"Admin\"},{\"UserId\":163,\"FirstName\":\"Alice\",\"BranchId\":17,\"BranchName\":\"Ratnapura\",\"RegionId\":1,\"RegionName\":\"Admin\"},{\"UserId\":264,\"FirstName\":\"Karen\",\"BranchId\":7,\"BranchName\":\"Peachtree\",\"RegionId\":3,\"RegionName\":\"South Region\"},{\"UserId\":266,\"FirstName\":\"Starla\",\"BranchId\":7,\"BranchName\":\"Peachtree\",\"RegionId\":3,\"RegionName\":\"South Region\"},{\"UserId\":30,\"FirstName\":\"Jane\",\"BranchId\":9,\"BranchName\":\"Henderson Mill\",\"RegionId\":3,\"RegionName\":\"South Region\"}]";

var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < Root >> (jsonResponse);
var jsonResponseList = myDeserializedClass.GroupBy(item = >item.RegionId).Select(grp = >grp.GroupBy(item = >item.BranchId)).Select(grp = >grp.Select(innerg = >innerg.GroupBy(item = >item.UserId))).ToList();

var serializer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponseList, Formatting.Indented);
```

Root class

```
public class Root
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}
```

and the output:

```
[
  [
    [
      [
        {
          "UserId": 195,
          "FirstName": "Carlton",
          "BranchId": 4,
          "BranchName": "Test",
          "RegionId": 1,
          "RegionName": "Admin"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "UserId": 223,
          "FirstName": "Lorenza",
          "BranchId": 4,
          "BranchName": "Test",
          "RegionId": 1,
          "RegionName": "Admin"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "UserId": 163,
          "FirstName": "Alice",
          "BranchId": 17,
          "BranchName": "Ratnapura",
          "RegionId": 1,
          "RegionName": "Admin"
        }
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [
        {
          "UserId": 264,
          "FirstName": "Karen",
          "BranchId": 7,
          "BranchName": "Peachtree",
          "RegionId": 3,
          "RegionName": "South Region"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "UserId": 266,
          "FirstName": "Starla",
          "BranchId": 7,
          "BranchName": "Peachtree",
          "RegionId": 3,
          "RegionName": "South Region"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "UserId": 30,
          "FirstName": "Jane",
          "BranchId": 9,
          "BranchName": "Henderson Mill",
          "RegionId": 3,
          "RegionName": "South Region"
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Linq [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) and [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) as following:

```
var regions = new List<Region>()
{
    new Region() { RegionId = 1, RegionName = "Admin" },
    new Region() { RegionId = 2, RegionName = "North Region" },
    new Region() { RegionId = 3, RegionName = "South Region" }
};

var branchs = new List<Branch>()
{
    new Branch() {BranchId = 1, BranchName = "Roswell Rd", FkRegionId = 3},
    new Branch() {BranchId = 2, BranchName = "Test", FkRegionId = 2},
    new Branch() {BranchId = 3, BranchName = "Piedmont Ave  ", FkRegionId = 2},
    new Branch() {BranchId = 4, BranchName = "Ashford Dunwoody  ", FkRegionId = 1},
};

var users = new List<User>()
{
    new User() {UserId = 1, FirstName = "Hasa", FkBranchId = 9},
    new User() {UserId = 2, FirstName = "Jane", FkBranchId = 1},
    new User() {UserId = 3, FirstName = "Joyce", FkBranchId = 7},
    new User() {UserId = 4, FirstName = "Jane", FkBranchId = 1},
    new User() {UserId = 5, FirstName = "John", FkBranchId = 3},
    new User() {UserId = 6, FirstName = "Sharon", FkBranchId = 8},
};


var tree = from user in users
           join branch in branchs on user.FkBranchId equals branch.BranchId
           join region in regions on branch.FkRegionId equals region.RegionId
           group region by new { region.RegionId, branch.BranchId } into grp
           select new
           {
               RegionName = regions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RegionId == grp.Key.RegionId).RegionName,
               Branchs = new
               {
                   BranchName = branchs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FkRegionId == grp.Key.RegionId).BranchName,
                   Users = users.Where(i => i.FkBranchId == grp.Key.BranchId).Select(s => new
                   {
                       FirstName = s.FirstName
                   })
               }
           };


var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, Formatting.Indented);
```

This will give you an expected result:

```
[
  {
    "RegionName": "South Region",
    "Branchs": {
      "BranchName": "Roswell Rd",
      "Users": [
        {
          "FirstName": "Jane"
        },
        {
          "FirstName": "Jane"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "RegionName": "North Region",
    "Branchs": {
      "BranchName": "Test",
      "Users": [
        {
          "FirstName": "John"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How can I bind this query result into model?

Comment: You can use `select new YourModel() {..}` in Linq. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750146/linq-select-to-new-object

Answer (score 0):

If these are physically related tables then EF has taken care of it already. Just make sure your lazy loading is ON or you can eager load data as well by using include and then display data as it is. If you want to eager load information then try this query

```
using(var db = new DBContext){
  var result = db.region.include(x => x.branches).theninclude(x => x.users).toList();
}
```

result will contain all of your data then bind that data into your custom define DTOs or you can directly bind entity models into views.
Its an overview of the code you can have your own implementation.

If there is no physical relations in between tables then use join using linq here is the link you can follow how joins works in linq.

[link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/sql-join-in-linq-linq-to-entity-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: Depending the volume of data lazy loading would be a really bad idea. #join_the_eager_loading_gang

Comment: Yeap Cleptus you are right that is why I provide eager loaded query but in some small projects lazy loading doesn't matter because of the less data.